# Is there a way to tell where your python file is?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-2.7

(Python2.7-3.2 on WindowsXP)
I used to use sys.arg[0], but now I'm executing it from a batch script(for determining if the user has python)

Thanks ^^

~ps: Suggest if you know a better way to find out if the user has Python

Comment: Hm? If you are running a Python script, then obviously the User has Python!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the variable `__file__` to find out the path to the current Python file being interpreted.

Comment: It's `__file__`, not `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at this posting that checks the registry

[batch file to check if Python is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920483/batch-file-to-check-if-python-is-installed)

seems to be easy as:

reg query "hkcu\software\Python 2.6"

An alternative is to check the %PATH%. I am not sure how to do that exactly, as do not have a installed windows around to test it:)

Try to find out more about "reg query" and how to search %PATH% for executables!

Good luck!!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: No, but it answers the PS question I asked, Bryan. Thanks, Obi. But do you know how to do it for python3? It seems to list Python2 in reg query "hkcu\software"

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, although it is already answered, here is something I got from this site (don't remember the source)

```
import os, sys
print "CWD: ", os.getcwd()
print "Script: ", sys.argv[0]
print ".EXE: ", os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
print "Script dir: ", os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
pathname, scriptname = os.path.split(sys.argv[0])
print "Relative script dir: ", pathname
print "Script dir: ", os.path.abspath(pathname)
print 'Current file: ', os.path.dirname(__file__)
print os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/IDLESTARTUP.txt'
```